# Search for own deleted answer

Tags: support, search, deleted-answers

Yesterday I answered a question but figured my answer was wrong, so I deleted it.  Now I'd like to do some more research.  But the answer is not listed in the "Answers" tab of my profile.

Is there a way to list your own deleted answers?

Comment: At the bottom of your answers list there should be a link named *"deleted recent answers"*.

Comment: Damn - forgot about that link.

Comment: That's why I am the moderator @ChrisF and you are... wait ... :p

Comment: @Bart: That's what I was looking for, thanks.  Is there a reason you can't search with a `deleted:yes` advanced search option?

Comment: @ChrisF I see you deleted your answer to check it out ;)

Comment: @ZachSaucier - nope. I deleted my *incorrect* answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[On your answers page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers&sort=newest)

right on the bottom there should be

[image]

A similar link exists at the bottom of your [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions&sort=newest) page

Comment: If you want to find your old deleted posts, you need a link (maybe from the reputation-page) or a moderator.