# Deleting lots of answers can ban me from answering?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

Some times I don't read post completely or OP is still editing the question and I answer. Sometimes I found my self in a hurry to answer incomplete question or may be incomplete for my mind at least.

Later on I tried to improve but I can't stop my self from answering and some times I have to delete answer to avoid downvote(s). I have did this lot of times.

Moreover I delete the post when I do not get any kind of response of OP for so many days or hours.

- Is that okay to delete inactive answers ?
- Can deleting lot of answers ban me from answering ?
- How can I find my all deleted posts as currently I got privilege to see deleted posts ?

Comment: My tip is to read the question carefully and write your answer carefully. There shouldn't be much cause to delete a whole stack of answers, instead just edit them into better shape.

Comment: @sevenseacat Thanks for your tip. I'll definitely do that. One thing we need while answering is speed with accuracy and sometimes I miss that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is that okay to delete inactive answers ?

It depends. If it is the only answer, it answers the question and didn't get down votes I wouldn't be bothered. Strictly speaking you aren't the one to decide to delete your answer as you given the license of your content to Stack Exchange, as explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260303/578411)

> Can deleting lot of answers ban me from answering ?

If you keep the statistics on mind mentioned by [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260303/578411)

> Having said that however, if you are deleting answers that are:
>
> 1. Zero or negative scoring.
> 2. On questions where there are other answers.
> 3. Incorrect in some way.
>
> then we generally don't have a problem with people cleaning up their accounts.

Your final point:

> How can I find my all deleted posts as currently I got privilege to see deleted posts

You can't if you didn't keep an url to the answer/questions you answered. You can only find the [deleted recent posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269939/578411) from your profile