# Does deleting many answers lead to anyone getting an answer ban?

Tags: discussion

I have read previously that deleting too many answers could potentially lead to a ban for further answering questions in the future. Does this apply to all users or just individuals with low reputation?

Comment: Why would you think this differs with reputation?  It's uncommon but not entirely unheard of for a user with 1K+ rep to have an answer ban.

Comment: @Makoto I don't think answer about deleted questions directly applies to deleted answers (at least I could not fine that answer in duplicate you selected).

Comment: Side note: "deleting too many answers" without any visible reason in relatively short time can lead to temporary account suspension, but it is not really "ban".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: if you have a better duplicate, I would encourage you to place it in the list.  From what I can tell, there's not much difference between the ban types besides q-bans being the most common.

Comment: @Makoto I don't have better duplicate (so voted to re-open). I actually don't remember any noticeable discussion on answer bans. Maybe we just need a sentece added to Q-ban question and keep this closed. Feels like getting A-ban is so hard that no one cares? I think the only practical way  to get A-ban is to post many bad comments as answers while being <50rep user...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: when I get near a computer, I'll look around for a more specific dupe.

Comment: Here's a better duplicate: [Deleting lots of answers can ban me from answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303137/deleting-lots-of-answers-can-ban-me-from-answering)

Comment: @Makoto actually I've found one:) FAQ clearly spelling out "Finally, deleted answers always count towards an automatic ban on new accounts." - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th. Just act of deleting answers is not a reason for A-ban.